# Make an animated container behave like collapsing toolbar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-sliver

[Image looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bhJf.png)

I have this widget that acts as a tab bar but was not create with a Tab bar. I want that widget to behave like a collapsing toolbar. Can anyone please help me out? This is the code
This is the code for the animated container which I want to behave like a collapsing toolbar...

Here is the code:

```
class Watching extends StatefulWidget {
      final set_state;

  const Watching(this.set_state, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WatchState createState() => _WatchState();
}

class _WatchState extends State<Watching> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> animation, animation2;
  final double startingHeight = 20.0;
  List pages = [];
  int index = 0;
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
  List titles = [feed, trending, explore];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pages = [
      MainPage(
        set_state: widget.set_state,
      ),
      TrendingPage(set_state: widget.set_state),
      ExplorePage()
    ];
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 5));
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 125, end: 150).animate(_controller);
    animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: 125, end: 150).animate(_controller);
    _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, twoFiftyDp),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.teal,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  width: animation.value,
                  height: animation.value <= 150 ? 150 : animation.value,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.teal,
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: RotationTransition(
                    turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(0 / 360),
                    child: ClipPath(
                      clipper: LeftRoundedClipper(flip: true),
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        width: animation2.value - 10,
                        height: animation2.value *
                            MediaQuery.of(context)
                                .size
                                .height, //<= 150 ? 200 :animation.value,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.teal,
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                Colors.lightGreen.withGreen(10),
                                Colors.greenAccent,
                                Colors.greenAccent
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: CurvedNavigationBar(
                    key: _bottomNavigationKey,
                    height: 65,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                    index: 0,
                    onTap: (value) {
                      switch (value) {
                        case 0:
                          /*    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 125, end: 0)
                              .animate(_controller);*/
                          animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: 125, end: 500)
                              .animate(_controller);
                          break;
                        case 1:
                          animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: 125, end: 700)
                              .animate(_controller);
                          /*  animation = Tween<double>(begin: -10, end: 50)
                              .animate(_controller);*/

                          break;
                        case 2:
                          animation = Tween<double>(begin: 125, end: 500)
                              .animate(_controller);

                          animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: 150, end: 200)
                              .animate(_controller);
                          break;
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        index = value;
                      });
                    },
                    items: [
                      Text(
                        Main,
                        style: index == 0
                            ? TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                            : TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        trending,
                        style: index == 1
                            ? TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                            : TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        explore,
                        style: index == 2
                            ? TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                            : TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: sixtyDp, left: tenDp),
                      child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                        titles[index],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: fiftyDp,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                    )),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: fiftyDp, left: twentyDp),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        index == 0
                            ? ShowIcon(
                                iconName: 'assets/icons/User.png',
                                onIconTap: () {},
                              )
                            : SizedBox(),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: fourteenDp),
                                child: ShowIcon(
                                  iconName: 'assets/icons/MagnifyingGlass.png',
                                  onIconTap: () {},
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: fourteenDp),
                                child: ShowIcon(
                                  iconName: 'assets/icons/BellRinging.png',
                                  onIconTap: () {},
                                ),
                              ),
                              ShowIcon(
                                iconName: 'assets/icons/PaperPlane.png',
                                onIconTap: () {},
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                        //  Spacer(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
       // body: pages[index],
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: pages.length, child: NestedScrollView(headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[

              
              SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([]))
            ];

        }, body: pages[index]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```